# Mutate function not working with function function

Tags: r, function, dplyr

I am following along a tidy-tuesday screencast, and trying to make the same function that the screencaster (Dave Robinson) is creating for making graphs of data.

The function I copied of his screencast looks like this:

```
plot_by_race <- function(data, column, labels = dollar) {

data %>%

  mutate(race = fct_reorder(race, -{{ column}}))%>%

  ggplot(aes(year, {{ column}}, color = race)) + 
  
  geom_line() + 

  expland_limits(y = 0) + 

  scale_y_continous(labels = labels)
}
```

However, when I run this function it returns:

```
Error in UseMethod("mutate_") : 
   no applicable method for 'mutate_' applied to an object of class "function".
```

This did not happen in the screencast, and the function worked fine there. Any ideas as to why?

Comment: This will likely "go away" if you rename your data set to something other than `data`, which is (also) a base R function.

Comment: That solved it straight away, thank you!